# erroring when using .split

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split this string down into sections:

```
2 h 3 12 s
```

From this I am trying to create a longer string such as:

```
00020312
DDHHMMSS
```

I am getting an error on line 21:

> Cannot read property split of undefined

```
//calculate which ticket is the oldest begining
            jQuery('.table-list-search tr').each(function(){
                var downTime = jQuery(this).find('.downTime').text();
                downTime = String(downTime);
                var hasDays = downTime.split("d");
                var hasHours = downTime.split("h");
                var hasMins = downTime.split("m");
                var hasSeconds = downTime.split("s");

                if(hasDays[1] === undefined){
                    var downTimeD = downTime.split(" d")[0];
                    downTime = downTime.split(" d ")[1];
                    if(downTimeD <=9){
                        downTimeD = downTimeD.toString(downTimeD);
                        downTimeD = '0' + downTimeD;
                    };
                }else{
                    var downTimeD = '00';
                };
                if(hasHours[1] === undefined){
                    var downTimeH = downTime.split(" h")[0];
                    downTime = downTime.split(" h ")[1];
                    if(downTimeH <=9){
                        downTimeH = downTimeH.toString(downTimeD);
                        downTimeH = '0' + downTimeH;
                    };
                }
```

Comment: you split on downTime and not in downTimeH

Comment: Firstly note that this has nothing to do with jQuery so I removed that tag. Secondly, I edited your code in to an executable snippet. When you run it the `split()` calls work absolutely fine. The error is because `downTimeD` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Also `downTimeH` (along with all the values resulting from `split()`) is a string, so comparing it to an integer literal will have some inconsistencies. Convert the string to an int using `parseInt()` before comparing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added the additional code, thanks for the down vote :/

Comment: @JoshWhiddett I haven't downvoted you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task can be done by applying a regular expression:

```js
const rx=/(?:(\d+) *d *)?(?:(\d+) *h *)?(?:(\d+) *m *)?(?:(\d+) *s *)?/;
const fmt=s=>(s||'0').padStart(2,'0');

console.log('DDHHMMSS')
console.log( rx.exec('2 h 3 m 12 s').slice(1).map(fmt).join('') )
console.log( rx.exec('1d24m'   ).slice(1).map(fmt).join('') )
```

The expression looks for (optional) groups of numbers with the letters 'd', 'h', 'm' or 's' behind them, qualifying each number in turn as "days", "hours", "minutes" and "seconds".

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8WfBWM0aSEBNnUru)

The result is returned as an array. From this array only the elements 1 to 4 being used, as the 0-th element would be the complete matched string.

The whole job can also be packed into a single function like:

```
fmta=dt=>/(?:(\d+) *d *)?(?:(\d+) *h *)?(?:(\d+) *m *)?(?:(\d+) *s *)?/
   .exec(dt).slice(1).map(s=>(s||'0').padStart(2,'0')).join('');
console.log(fmta('12d6h56m 45s')); // '12065645'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `downTime` come from? The error you're getting means that the variable does not exist. It might be a typo somewhere.

Edit - this was posted before the question contained a full code snippet, but the answer stands - if you get such an error, it usually is because the variable is not defined.

Edit 2 - There are a number of weird things in the logic. First `if(hasDays[1] === undefined)` essentially translates to "`downTime` has no 'd' in it", so all further attempts to break on 'd' do not split the string. So `downTime = downTime.split(" d ")[1];` would never yield anything - `downTime` has no d's, so it can't be split on them.

Then there' a corner case in the line `downTime = downTime.split(" d ")[1];` (and the similar one below). You're splitting on `" d "`while the above splits are on `" d"` and `"d"`.

In summary, you would like to change `if(hasDays[1] === undefined)` to `if(hasDays[1] !== undefined)` and always split on `"d"` with no extra spaces, and the same for the things below.